# How to set unique values in multiple rows while doing UPDATE in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table with several columns. The only way to tell the connection to each row is by session_id 
My goal is to update the age column with a random number. 
Therefore I used following query

```
UPDATE userdata
SET age = (FLOOR(18 + RAND() * 62))
WHERE session_id IN 
(
    SELECT session_id FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT session_id
        FROM userdata
    ) AS temp
)
```

This works fine but every distinct session_id still has multiple rows and the age has different values.I know this query does what it should do but how can I change my query to get unique age values for each row with the same session_id?

e.g.

```
session_id  |  age
1              25
2              35
2              35
3              51
3              51
3              51
```

Thank you in advance and please be nice, since this is my first stackoverflow question.

Comment: To clarify, you want a different random age for every row? Or just every row for a specific session_id?

Comment: @sorayadragon Every row with a specific session_id. At the moment, I have different age values although the session_id is the same.

Comment: Ok, so each unique session_id should have the *same* age value for all its rows and different session_ids should have different ages values?

Comment: yes thats right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
update userdata
inner join (select *, (FLOOR(18 + RAND() * 62)) as age2 from userdata group by session_id) T ON T.session_id = userdata.session_id
set userdata.age = T.age2
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems the wrong way around.  It seems session_id is not unique (when perhaps it should be?--which is where the first way you can correct this is)... so you are trying to create a unique column based on it...but as you rightly point out you can't create a new number based on the session id as it too will be the same.  Most obvious solution, add an auto-increment column:

ALTER TABLE yourtablename add Age int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;

Comment: I tried this and got a **Multiple primaray key defined** error.

Comment: For calrification. I have multiple rows and every session id has several listings but different values in other columns. Though the age should be same for a specific session_id.

Comment: Hmmm... isn't that what your original table actually achieved already? For example, session 2 is age 35 multiple times?

Comment: I have 3 primary keys to be specific.I need it to be like that.The combination of these  keys allow me to have several rows with the same session_id which is unique.

Comment: If you decide there really is a deeper issue... and you do want a real primary key like given above... you would simply remove whatever is currently defined as the primary key from your table before adding the auto increment primary key.

Comment: I am sorry if i can not explain it right. At the moment I have different random numbers for age although the session_id is the same. What I need is the table in the question as example.